# Как отсортировать многомерный массив

Tags: php

Как отсортировать многомерный, ассоциативный  массив по времени?

```
   $posts = [
             ['name'=>'David', 'time' => '2013-04-01 22:29:49'],
             ['name'=>'Vasya', 'time' => '2011-04-01 09:29:51'],
             ['name'=>'Mark', 'time' => '2013-04-02 19:29:45'],
             ['name'=>'Curka', 'time' => '2013-04-01 10:49:13']
           ]
```

Comment: хранить время в секундах, возвращаемых функцией time()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так?

```
 function cmp($a, $b)
 {
     return strcmp($a["time"], $b["time"]);
 };
 usort($posts, "cmp");
```

Кроме usort есть ещё uasort и uksort